Apparent contradiction in the Aruch Hashulchan regarding the laws of the morning blessings
The Aruch Hashulchan (OC 47:16) asks how is it that one can fulfill the obligation of Birchas Hatorah by reciting the Brachah of “Ahavah Rabbah”, being that the main parts of a Brachah are the beginning and the end, and he goes on to explain the connection between the beginning and end of “Ahavah Rabbah” to Birchas Hatorah.
Now later on (OC 52:8) the Aruch Hashulchan writes that he does not know of any reason why one would not fulfill the obligation of the Brachah of “Matir Asurim” by reciting those words in the Brachah of “Mechayeh Hameisim”.
The question is: didn’t he write previously that the main parts of a Brachah are the beginning and end? if so, in this case, there doesn’t seem to be an apparent connection between the words “Matir Asurim” to the end of the Brachah of “Mechayeh Hameisim”?
P.S. thanks to @DoubleAA for bringing the second Aruch Hashulchan to my attention here!

+1 Good teamwork! :)

Maybe the AhSh distinguishes between a bracha that has a sufficiently parallel theme, and a bracha that literally has as a proper subset the full text of another bracha.

Maybe the AhSh thinks the chatima of mechayei hameisim is sufficiently related to mattir asurim, both being about God's powers. After all we dont stick the words mattir asurim in that bracha by accident

@DoubleAA thanks. Regarding your last sentence, it just seems from the fact that by Birchas Hatorah, the AH feels the need to explain how the beginning and end are sufficiently related, that there isn’t always an obvious connection between the middle and end…

It certainly possible that there isn't always a connection, but here Mattir Asurim and Mechaye Meitim seem pretty obviously parallel to me (allowing freedom to something stuck). The real problem for this is if Mattir Asurim is thematically like Gevuros, and Gevuros is thematically like Elokei Neshama, then every morning we should be stuck after saying Elokei Neshama!

The blessing over the Torah is different from other blessings, because there's a mitzvah (Torah-level, according to all opinions according to the Aroch Hashulchan 47:2) to say a blessing before studying Torah, while the other blessings are general expressions of praise and thanks but not independent obligations. If you haven't fulfilled your mitzvah obligation, you still have to say it. But if it's just an expression of praise, you don't repeat a (rabbinic) blessing unless you're innovating something you haven't already said, and possibly even something that isn't somehow included by implication (as in 46:12 for שלא עשני blessings).
So (it seems to me), it doesn't matter how many times you mention the Torah in a blessing, as long as you haven't said a blessing on the Torah you still need to say it. That's why he has to prove that the beginning and end of the blessing are about the Torah, to prove that this is an actual blessing on the Torah, not one that mentions the Torah incidentally. For anything else, an incidental mention is enough of a reason not to repeat it.
A second possibility: Assume that the above principle (that the blessing needs to be on the Torah and not just mention the Torah) is doubtful (as indeed he does express doubt regarding whether the similar themes of the other blessings exempt each other, 52:8). Even calling this a doubt, you would still need to repeat the blessing over the Torah in a case of doubt, because it's a Torah-level obligation (47:6). Whereas for the other blessings, which are rabbinic, the guiding principle he mentions behind not repeating them as the rule ספק ברכות להקל, which only applies to the rabbinic blessings and not to the blessing over the Torah (46:12, 52:8).
